# Mock or hide base class when unit testing in xunit

Tags: c#, moq, xunit, base-class

I am trying to write a test case for a method, that inside calls a method of the base class.

```
 protected override void OnServerStarting(ApplicationConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Log.Logger.Information("The server is starting.");

        base.OnServerStarting(configuration);

        // it is up to the application to decide how to validate user identity tokens.
        // this function creates validator for X509 identity tokens.
        CreateUserIdentityValidators(configuration);
    }
```

I just want to call CreateUserIdentityValidators (private) method. However, the base class method gets called and tries to do stuff like creating/reading certificates and throws exception.

Is there a way to hide/override/mock the base class method? Using moq and xunit here.

Comment: If you just want to test `CreateUserIdentityValidators` why not put that in its own class and unit test that - it can be called from within `OnServerStarting`

Comment: I am not allowed to modify the existing code. Also, are you suggesting pulling out the method to a different class and making that method public?

Comment: The Stackoverflow community allows you to modify the code! P.S. Quit this job.

Comment: Yes, there are ways that will allow you to change the behavior of the current code without changing it. In particular, this can be done using _unconstrained_ mocking tools such as TypeMock, JustMock, MS Fakes (all three are paid), or free alternatives: Prig, Ionad.Fody, AutoFake, Unmockable, Harmony, MethodRedirect, Pose, Shimmy.

Comment: It is impossible with constrained frameworks like Moq, NSubstitute, FakeItEasy.

Comment: @AmitKumar sometimes code needs to be modified to be tested. That is not bad, it only means it was not initially designed to be tested in a specific way